# Jms Serializer don't call constructor

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm using Symfony 2.8 with JMS Serializer and when i use deserializer method the constructor of my entity class is not called. See my code:

my service.yml

```
jms_serializer.unserialize_object_constructor:
    class: AppBundle\Serializer\ObjectConstructor
```

my ObjectConstructor

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Serializer;

use JMS\Serializer\VisitorInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\Metadata\ClassMetadata;
use JMS\Serializer\DeserializationContext;
use JMS\Serializer\Construction\ObjectConstructorInterface;

class ObjectConstructor implements ObjectConstructorInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function construct(VisitorInterface $visitor, ClassMetadata $metadata, $data, array $type, DeserializationContext $context ) {

        $className = $metadata->name;

        return new $className();
    }
}
```

and constructor of my class:

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->dateTime = new \DateTime();
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You should alias your custom constructor service like so

```
jms_serializer.object_constructor:
    alias: your_service_id
```

Comment: Now if i add the construct method in ObjectConstructor is called but the method construct of class ObjectConstructor not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's outdated, but your `ObjectConstructor` has the wrong method name `construct` while it should be `__construct()`. Probably that is the reason why it's not called.

Comment: no. it's correct because of ObjectConstructorInterface